# How to populate multiple columns based on different value in one column

Tags: excel

I have an excel file as:

```
+----+------------+
| ID | Order date |
+----+------------+
| A  | 1/1/2011   |
| A  | 1/3/2012   |
| A  | 1/8/2013   |
| A  | 1/20/2014  |
| A  | 1/23/2015  |
| B  | 1/1/2011   |
| B  | 1/20/2014  |
| B  | 1/23/2015  |
+----+------------+
```

I want to convert it in a report that informs me what all years did the person bought the product in the below format:

```
+----+------------+-----------+------+------+------+-----+
| ID | Order date | 2011 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 |     |
+----+------------+-----------+------+------+------+-----+
| A  | 1/1/2011   | Yes       | No   | No   | No   | No  |
| A  | 1/3/2012   | No        | Yes  | No   | No   | No  |
| A  | 1/8/2013   | No        | No   | Yes  | No   | No  |
| A  | 1/20/2014  | No        | No   | No   | Yes  | No  |
| A  | 1/23/2015  | No        | No   | No   | No   | Yes |
| B  | 1/1/2011   | Yes       | No   | No   | No   | No  |
| B  | 1/20/2014  | No        | No   | No   | Yes  | No  |
| B  | 1/23/2015  | No        | No   | No   | No   | Yes |
+----+------------+-----------+------+------+------+-----+
```

any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data is in column A and B, with a header row, and you have the years going across the top, you can use this (place in C2):

`=IF(YEAR($B2)=C$1,"Yes","No")` and drag over and down.

[image]

Pretty straightforward. It takes the `YEAR` from column B, checks against the year in the current column's header row, and puts "Yes" if they match.

A note, we didn't do anything with the IDs.  Perhaps that's okay, but I'm thinking you included them in your sample for some reason (maybe not though), so if you want to whittle this down further, update your OP.

edit: For funsies, in case you just want to drag willy-nilly, add a statement to leave it blank if there's no data in B: `=If($B2<>"",IF(YEAR($B2)=C$1,"Yes","No"),"")`

Comment: Thanks Bruce. I had thought of the same method, but was wondering if there is a faster way to populate the data. This confirms it!

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawal - Yeah, I was thinking if there's a quicker way. I don't really think so - perhaps with VBA but then we're really just speeding up a quick process by maybe .5 seconds, and it's kind of overkill.  Unless the above is really hampering your work (in other words, you'd like it to be faster), I think that's the most efficient solution.